# Dictionary key name from variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a nested dictionary, whereby the key to each nested dictionary is named from the value from a variable.  My end result should look something like this:

```
data_dict = {
    'jane': {'name': 'jane', 'email': 'jane@example.com'}, 
    'jim': {'name': 'jim', 'email': 'jim@example.com'}
}
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
data_dict = {}
s = "jane"
data_dict[s][name] = 'jane'
```

To my surprise, this does not work.  Is this possible?

Comment: data_dict[s]['name'] = 'jane'

Comment: I think you should first set `data_dict[s]` to an empty dictionary and then add a `name` key to that empty dictionary with the value you want.

Answer (score 4):

You want something like:

```
data_dict = {}
s = "jane"
data_dict[s] = {}
data_dict[s]['name'] = s
```

That should work, though I would recommend instead of a nested dictionary that you use a dictionary of names to either namedtuples or instances of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data_dict = {}
s = ["jane", "jim"]
for name in s:
    data_dict[name] = {}
    data_dict[name]['name'] = name
    data_dict[name]['email'] = name + '@example.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

For existing dictionaries you can do `dict[key] = value` although if there is no `dict` that would raise an error. I think this is the code you want to have:

```
data_dict = {}
s = "jane"
data_dict[s] = {"name": s, "email": f"{s}@example.com"}

print(data_dict)
```

I just realized when I got a notification about this question:

```
data_dict = defaultdict(dict)

data_dict["jane"]["name"] = "jane"
```

Would be a better answer I think.

Answer (score 1):

as @Milad in the comment mentioned, you first need to initialize `s` as empty dictionary first

```
data={}
data['Tom']={}
data['Tom']['name'] = 'Tom Marvolo Riddle'
data['Tom']['email'] = 'iamlordvoldermort.com'
```